# 'Unexpected token < ' Error from a link to css file?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a [web page](http://heseg.com/events/?lang=he) that uses the [all-in-one-calendar](http://time.ly) plugin (In a Wordpress website).
After upgrading I am getting this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and the calendar is not loaded.

Checking the source code I found this line which obviously doing something wrong as the `herf` is the website base URL and defiantly not the link to the style  sheet of the plugin (ai1ec is  the short name that refers to the plugin in it's own code).

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ai1ec_style-css'  href='http://heseg.com/' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

1. Is that the problem ?
2. Is there a way to track which php file generate this css link ?
3. Is there a way to programatically remove this request before it is called without massing with the plugin code ?

**EDIT**
1. It looks like the the problem is gone when replacing the theme to the WP default theme.
2. When I am logged in as admin the error is still there but the calendar loads fine.

Any Idea ?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: that looks more like a JavaScript error to me. If you're using the Chrome console (probably works for others as well) you should be able to expand the area where the error occurs and also the file name. If you can provide this info I'll see if I can debug it.

Comment: Do you have missing script closure tag (`</script>`)?

Comment: @JoeBuckle it looks like it points to the same document and more precisely  to the '<!DOCTYPE html>' line. Thanks

Comment: The `link` element with `rel='stylesheet'` and `href='http://heseg.com/'` is certainly in error, since the URL does not refer to a stylesheet. It seems to cause different issues on different browsers, but the important thing is to track down the code that generates it. I’m afraid this cannot be seen from outside your authoring environment.

Comment: Added more data to the question

Comment: if this is a problem with the config of a third-party WP plugin (which it sounds like it may be), then it might be better to ask this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.